Is it valid to separate text generation and logits computation in reinforcement learning?
I'm working with a reinforcement learning setup using the REINFORCE algorithm for a text summarization task in NLP. Originally, I developed a setup by extending Huggingface's .generate() function, where I collected log probabilities directly during text generation by setting the model to training mode before calling .generate() like below [the code is simplified for the sake of understandability]:
model.train()
# Sampling a text and collecting the logits/logprobs...
# ... via the extended .generate() function:
output = model.generate(
    do_sample=True,
    **inputs
)
# The output has sequence and collected logits

However, this method was computationally intensive, so I'm considering a new approach that involves two distinct phases: generating text samples (through sampling) without gradient tracking and then computing the logits for these samples with gradient tracking. Here's the new approach I'm considering:
model.eval()
with torch.no_grad():
    output_sequence = model.generate(do_sample=True, **inputs)  
    # Sampling happens here with Huggingface's .generate() function

model.train()
inputs["decoder_input_ids"] = output_sequence
output = model(**inputs)  # Logits are computed here, and gradients are tracked

I am doing this because I want to optimize the computational efficiency during the sampling phase while still being able to compute and backpropagate based on the logits of the generated text.
Questions:

Is this new approach that I'm considering valid in the context of reinforcement learning? as with logits, the logprobs will be calculated, playing a key role in the REINFORCE algorithm.
What are the implications of not tracking gradients during the text generation phase in terms of the model's learning capability, especially concerning the policy gradient methods like REINFORCE?
Compared to my original method that I had (the method #1), will this new approach lead to inefficiencies or missed learning opportunities in the RL context, and how might it be modified for better integration of sampling and learning?

